# Data grid written in pure JavaScript

Tags: datagrid, user-experience

Is there any Data grid similar to ui-grid ( https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid ) written in jquery or pure JavaScript?

I need one with this set of functionality:

- sort
- search
- horizontal and vertical scroll
- grouping
- inline editing
- lazy load
- column resizing
- pinning
- pagination
- selection

Answer (score 0):

https://jsgrids.statico.io/ is a list of JavaScript grid libraries that lets you filter. Using that site and given your requirements, the following libraries meet your specifications:

- [ag-Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/)
- [Kendo UI Grid](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid)
- [FancyGrid](https://fancygrid.com/)
- [ParamQuery](https://paramquery.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I have used https://limegrid.co, vanilla javascript - has some themes looks a bit like excel.